# Serial Upvoting

Tags: support

Nobody bothered to answer my edited [question yesterday](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4163/too-many-up-votes-again-fourth-time-lucky). So I'll write a new question but ask about the same things.

In less than a month I have had rep points reversed three times. I'd like to know what is StackExchange's policy concerning serial upvoters. Presumably the mods know who this or these persons are. Does the person who upvoted thirty questions in under five minutes yesterday know that his/her votes have been reversed? Are *they* penalized in any way?

Presumably, the happy serial upvoter is someone who has earned at least 15 rep points, the minimum number of points necessary in order to gain the privilege of upvoting answers, so it can't be a complete outsider. I can't believe it is a veteran user but anything is possible with sockpuppets. My instincts are telling me that the behaviour is ironically, malicious, and I'm guessing it's the same offender. Am I right?

Comment: I'm confused about your last paragraph. How can someone upvote in order to get the privilege to upvote? Also, how can it be malicious? How are you hurt by this other than being driven mad out of curiosity?

Comment: @mitch the serial voter has to be someone who has earned at least 15 rep points before he or she can upvote any answers. How can I be hurt? It's bloody annoying to see 200 rep points wiped off three times in a row, even if they weren't earned *honestly*. And... I have a paranoid streak in me.

Comment: 30 in 5 min. is *really* steep, especially if they are all from the same user. My MO is read-vote?-next, but I think one can have a string of honest upvotes occurring in rapid succession from one user: If they open all promising front-page questions in new tabs, read the answers carefully and keep the tab centered on the answer they wish to upvote before moving to the next, and leave after using hotkeys like CTRL+PGUP to do a sweep of voting. In this case the behavior looks spammy, even though it may be honest, thoughtful, maybe efficient. How does SE inform the offender about rescinded votes?

Comment: Looking at your recent reputation changes, I'd say you should brace yourself for some more losses. In my experience it's unusual to suddenly get 10-20 past questions upvoted in a single day, and in the last few weeks that's happened to you half a dozen times. Three of them have been almost totally reversed, but on each occasion the *previous* day's votes look atypical. Nothing like much earlier days on which you've got 200 rep points mainly fueled by one or two highly-rated answers. Those three remaining recent "good" days for you also look highly suspect to me, so expect the worst.

Comment: Ahh, thanks   @FumbleFingers, that would explain why I mysteriously lost 20 rep points yesterday, those points were linked to the same happy serial upvoter(s) I imagine. Great news :7/

Comment: Not long ago there was a case of serial upvoting in Portuguese Language SE. It was quite clearly a user voting for the suffrage and vox popoli badges (30 and 40 votes in a day). It was a new user with the 100-point association bonus. Small crowd there, so easier to work out who’s doing these things. It is strange that it happened to you three times in a single month though. So maybe it was something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not at liberty to discuss specific details, but I can assure you that the moderators are aware of the situation at hand.